# String#replaceAll() to replace *anything but a =* group

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I have a parameter of key-value like this:

```
sign="aaaabbbb="
```

And I want to get the parameter name `sign` and the value `"aaaabbb="`(with quote signs)

I thought I could split the string with `=` to get the first elem of the array which is the parameter name and do a `String.replaceAll()` to remove the `sign=` to get the value. Anyway here is my sample code:

```
public class TestStringReplace {
    public static void main(String[] argvs){
        String s = "sign=\"aaaabbbb=\"";
        String[] ss = s.split("=");
        String value = s.replaceAll("\\[^=]+=","");
        //EDIT:        s.replaceAll("[^=]+=","") will not do the job either.
        System.out.println(ss[0]);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

but the output shows this:

```
sign
sign="aaaabbbb="
```

Why `\\[^=]+=` not matching `sign=` and replace it with empty string here?Quite a newbie of Java regex, need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just limit your `split()` to the first occurrence of `=` like so: `s.split("=", 1);`

Comment: What do you think that leading backslash is doing?

Comment: Check out Regex Planet, I have found it very useful for regex issues: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @willOEM really spark idea, but it should be `s.split("=",2)` thanks :-)

Comment: Try this:- String value = s.substring(s.indexOf("\"") +1, s.lastIndexOf("\""));

Comment: @Arjit A good alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off with an actual `Pattern` and back-references here.

For instance:

```
String[] test = {
    "sign=\"aaaabbbb=\"",
    // assuming a HTTP GET-styled parameter list
    "blah?sign=\"aaaabbbb=\"",
    "foo?sign=\"aaaabbbb=\"&blah=\"hodor\""
};
//                           | group 1: literal "sign"
//                           |      | literal key-value delimiter and double quote
//                           |      | | group 2: any character reluctantly quantified
//                           |      | |   | literal ending double quote
//                           |      | |   |  | look-ahead for either "&" or end
//                           |      | |   |  | 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(sign)=\"(.+?)\"(?=$|&)");
Matcher m = null;
for (String s: test) {
    m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf(
            "Found key: \"%s\" and value: \"%s\"%n", m.group(1), m.group(2)
        );
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Found key: "sign" and value: "aaaabbbb="
Found key: "sign" and value: "aaaabbbb="
Found key: "sign" and value: "aaaabbbb="
```

**Notes**

- I'm assuming a HTTP GET styled parameter list, but maybe you don't need to actually check for a next parameter key-value pair delimiter (i.e. `&`) - in which case you can remove the `&` part
- I'm **also** assuming you want the `"`s out of your value back-reference, which kind of makes the following `&` check useless
- Your current pattern for the `replaceAll` invocation will match as follows:

  ```
  // | literal "[" (double-escaped)
  // ||literal "^" or "=" (in character class)
  // ||  | ... greedily quantified (1+ occurrences)
  // ||  || literal "="
  "\\[^=]+="
  ```
- Finally, if you **really, really** want to use `String#replaceAll` for this, here's a slightly different pattern than the one above:

  ```
  for (String s: test) {
          System.out.println(
              s.replaceAll(
                  ".*(sign)=\"(.+?)\"(?=$|&).*", 
                  "Found key: \"$1\" and value: \"$2\""
              )
          );
  }
  ```
- It still uses back-references and will produce the same result, albeit in a uglier way: you can't reuse the `$1` and `$2` group values, since you're creating a new `String` replacing the original one.
- Last possible solution, using `String#'split`. This is the ugliest as it won't work well with a list of parameters:

  ```
  for (String s: test) {
      System.out.println(
          //                       | negative look-behind for start of input
          //                       |    | literal "="
          //                       |    |  | literal "
          //                       |    |  | 
          Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<!^)=\""))
      );
  }
  ```

  **Output**

  ```
  [sign, aaaabbbb]
  [blah?sign, aaaabbbb] --> yuck
  [foo?sign, aaaabbbb, &blah, hodor"] --> yuck again
  ```

Comment: A great answer, thanks, but I am sort of afraid of the back references things , in fact if just split and other trick will do the job, I will never give regex back references a shot. :-D

Comment: @armnotstrong you're welcome. IMO you shouldn't be afraid of a solution that's essentially made for the purpose you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex `^\\w+=` with `replaceAll(`) instead of your regex:

```
public class TestStringReplace {
public static void main(String[] argvs){
    String s = "sign=\"aaaabbbb=\"";
    String[] ss = s.split("=");
    String value = s.replaceAll("^\\w+=","");
    System.out.println(ss[0]);
    System.out.println(value);
}
}
```

This will remove the `sign=`.

You can see the [**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/9GAWYg) here.

**Note** that with your `"\\[^=]+="`  regex you were trying to match the character `[` literally in the beginning of your regex.

And it explains why you got `sign="aaaabbbb="` as a result with `replaceAll()` which didn't replace anything because there's no match.

Comment: Good one thanks, but I still don't know why `[^=]+=` don't work, I now know that \\ will be the escape, but why I what to match a `"` it should be \\\" ?weird :-( And why not use just one \  as a escape as normally some language does?

Comment: @armnotstrong It didn't work because `[^=]+=` will also match `aaaabbbb=` and the rresult value will be `"` .

Comment: @armnotstrong did my answer help you? if so please accept/vote it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can use the following:

```
String str = "sign=\"aaaabbbb=\"";
String var1 = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('='));
String var2 = str.substring(str.indexOf('=')+1);
System.out.println("var1="+var1+", var2="+var2);
```

The above would have the following output:

var1=sign, var2="aaaabbbb="

Answer (score 0):

The double slash is a mistake, because it is escaping the `[` to a *literal* `[`, which will never match.

Instead, do this:

```
String name = s.replaceAll("=.*", "");
String value = s.replaceAll(".*?=", "");
```

Comment: note that `.*=` may not wok, there may be a `=` sign in the value :-)

Comment: @armnotstrong quite so. I have altered by regex to cater for that (by making the quantifier reluctant)